# Convolution without FFT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity, fft, convolution

What is the best upper and lower bound known for [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) without [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)?

Is FFT proven to be essential for time complexity reduction? 
Is cancellation essential as well?

Comment: It might be a good idea to clarify what you mean by FFT being essential for convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Toom-Cook multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) and see if that is helpful for what you need. The complexity is $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for any fixed $\epsilon>0$.